# Is done() required if node-postgres .connect() returns with an error?

Tags: node-postgres

From the docs it sounds like err is not null if there was a problem getting a client from the pool.  If that's the case, does it mean done() doesn't need to be called?

```
pg.connect(connString, function(err, client, done){
    if (err) { done(); return err; }

    ...
});
```

or

```
pg.connect(connString, function(err, client, done){
    if (err) { return err; }

    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only call `done()` when `connect()` was successful, i.e. `err` is `null` or `undefined`.

So the second example is correct.